# Open PWA/website when web push notification is clicked

Tags: android, android-notifications, progressive-web-apps, web-push, chrome-for-android

I have a simple PWA which sends web push notifications to Android users. I want the PWA to be opened (either the installed app, or whichever browser receives the notification), and following the method outlined [in this guide](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/chapter-05/04-common-notification-patterns/), I've ended up with the following event listener:

```js
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    const clickedNotification = event.notification;
    clickedNotification.close();
    const promiseChain = clients.openWindow('/');
    event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
});
```

The listener is invoked and the notification is indeed closed, but the website is generally not opened: If I click the notification from the lock screen, the screen unlocks but in *most* cases, it then goes on to simply display the Android home screen rather than the app (and I haven't figured out what causes the inconsistency). This is on Chrome 80.0.3987.149 on Android 10.

Should I be doing something else than the above?

Comment: if you get solution, please post here. I am unable to open pwa when click on notification.